# Build vs. Rebuild: aren't the names wrong?

Tags: visual-studio, build, rebuild

I understand the difference, and SO has a number of postings that explain in detail.  But my question is just a curiosity: aren't the names backward?  I'd like to think that "build" would mean "build as if its the first time" and "Re-build" would mean "build, considering what I built before" .  But, not so, it's the other way around.  Is anyone with me on this or am I just marching to a different drummer?

Is this just visual studio, or is this the terminology in other environs (e.g, eclipse, NetBeans).

Call me curious.

Comment: It should be called *Clean and Build*.

Comment: At least the part that an unqualified "build" is allowed to reuse the compiler output for files that didn't change since the last build is pretty universal.

Comment: @Elroy - you've asked six questions and accepted no answers - please read the faq and accept some answers since it's highly unlikely none of these answers was helpful/correct

Comment: This is a discussion question.  It doesn't belong here.

Comment: Jeez,that's embarrassing in multiple ways. I probably read the faq once but forgot that SO isn't for discussion.  Regarding the "accepted no answers part: now I know, OK will do. (edited to answer my own embedded question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I see build as just a normal build, if there's something there you use it and build upon it, and if not you build from the ground up, and rebuild as actively paying attention to what is already there and removing it, because you *want* to build from the ground up.

Then again I might be brain washed, who knows..